# Static S3 website (React SPA) logging to Elasticsearch

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, static-site

I'm trying to determine the best Elasticsearch logging strategy for a static S3 website - in my case a React single page application (SPA).

I already have an AWS-hosted ELK stack that I use for other components of my service. I currently use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) on EC2 to directly ship logs to my [private VPC Elasticsearch cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html).

[Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) has a [plugin to handle S3 access logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html). I can enable logging in the SPA website bucket, set up Logstash, and ship the logs. Is there a better solution than a dedicated EC2 instance/docker container with Logstash installed to ship poll and ship logs as they are written to S3? My concern is that this comes with additional monitoring overhead.

What is the [currently] easiest way to ship S3 access logs for a static S3 website to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AWS Lambda we can stream logs from S3 for ES. AWS already documented the procedure:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es